Issues in running lint and jest tests on a fresh nx workspace
npx create-nx-workspace --pm pnpm

nx generate @nx/js:lib utils --directory=libs

nx lint utils
Error: The externalDependency 'eslint' for 'utils:lint' could not be found

nx test utils
Error: The externalDependency 'jest' for 'utils:test' could not be found

Here is what my package.json looks like
{
  "name": "@simple-nx-workspace/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": { },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nx/eslint": "19.0.1",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "19.0.1",
    "@nx/jest": "19.0.1",
    "@nx/js": "19.0.1",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.0.1",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.8.0",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.85",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint": "~8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.4.1",
    "nx": "19.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

Tried reinstalling dependencies but did not help. Ideally would want to avoid installing global dependencies. Any feedback around what might be the issue?

Downgrading my pnpm version to 8.5.1 fixed this.
